# How can I figure out why the Rails 4 gems are getting installed?

Tags: bundler

I recently did a `bundle update` and noticed that the system was retrieving and installing a lot of Rails 4.0 gems. I didn't request any Rails 4.0 gems explicitly (all the versions I listed explicitly are 3.2 version) and I don't see any 4.0 gems listed in `Gemfile.lock`, even in the DEPENDENCIES section. Can someone help me understand what's going on?  I've include my Gemfile, Gemfile.lock and `gem list` output below.  I'm using rvm.

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'rake', '10.1.0'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
gem 'childprocess', '0.3.9'
gem 'highcharts-rails'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'google_drive'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'thin'
gem 'coffee-script'
gem 'therubyracer', :require => 'v8'
gem 'underscore-rails'
gem 'date_easter'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.1'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
  gem 'annotate', '2.5.0'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem "jasminerice", :git => 'https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice.git'
  gem 'guard-jasmine'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'simplecov', require: false
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.2.1', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.7.0'
  # gem 'launchy', '2.1.0'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.9.1', :require => false
  gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
end
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GIT
  remote: https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice.git
  revision: d93a3b2ed8f9b74249e2f19d179b5b1f1963dfc3
  specs:
    jasminerice (0.1.0)
      coffee-rails

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.11)
      actionpack (= 3.2.11)
      mail (~> 2.4.4)
    actionpack (3.2.11)
      activemodel (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.11)
      activemodel (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.11)
      activemodel (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
    activesupport (3.2.11)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    annotate (2.5.0)
      rake
    arel (3.0.2)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (2.3.2.1)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.9)
      will_paginate
    builder (3.0.4)
    capybara (1.1.2)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 2.0)
      xpath (~> 0.1.4)
    childprocess (0.3.9)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    coderay (1.0.9)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
    cucumber (1.3.5)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3)
      gherkin (~> 2.12.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.7.5)
      multi_test (>= 0.0.2)
    cucumber-rails (1.2.1)
      capybara (>= 1.1.2)
      cucumber (>= 1.1.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.0)
    daemons (1.1.9)
    database_cleaner (0.7.0)
    date_easter (0.0.1)
    diff-lcs (1.1.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.3)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    factory_girl (4.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.1.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faker (1.0.1)
      i18n (~> 0.4)
    faraday (0.8.7)
      multipart-post (~> 1.1)
    ffi (1.9.0)
    formatador (0.2.4)
    gherkin (2.12.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
    google_drive (0.3.6)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4, != 1.5.2, != 1.5.1)
      oauth (>= 0.3.6)
      oauth2 (>= 0.5.0)
    growl (1.0.3)
    guard (1.7.0)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (>= 0.6.0)
      lumberjack (>= 1.0.2)
      pry (>= 0.9.10)
      thor (>= 0.14.6)
    guard-jasmine (1.17.0)
      childprocess
      guard (>= 1.1.0)
      multi_json
      thor
      tilt
    guard-rspec (1.2.1)
      guard (>= 1.1)
    guard-spork (1.5.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.3)
      guard (>= 1.1)
      spork (>= 0.8.4)
    hashie (2.0.5)
    highcharts-rails (3.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    hike (1.2.3)
    httpauth (0.2.0)
    i18n (0.6.4)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.2.0, < 5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    jquery-ui-rails (4.0.3)
      jquery-rails
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
    json (1.8.0)
    jwt (0.1.8)
      multi_json (>= 1.5)
    libv8 (3.11.8.17)
    listen (0.7.3)
    lumberjack (1.0.4)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    method_source (0.8.1)
    mime-types (1.23)
    mini_portile (0.5.1)
    multi_json (1.7.7)
    multi_test (0.0.2)
    multipart-post (1.2.0)
    newrelic_rpm (3.6.5.130)
    nokogiri (1.6.0)
      mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
    oauth (0.4.7)
    oauth2 (0.8.1)
      faraday (~> 0.8)
      httpauth (~> 0.1)
      jwt (~> 0.1.4)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.2)
    omniauth (1.1.4)
      hashie (>= 1.2, < 3)
      rack
    omniauth-facebook (1.4.1)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.1.0)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1)
      oauth2 (~> 0.8.0)
      omniauth (~> 1.0)
    pg (0.12.2)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    pry (0.9.12.2)
      coderay (~> 1.0.5)
      method_source (~> 0.8)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    quiet_assets (1.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
    rack (1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.11)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.11)
      actionpack (= 3.2.11)
      activerecord (= 3.2.11)
      activeresource (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.11)
    railties (3.2.11)
      actionpack (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.1.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.1)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    ref (1.0.5)
    rspec (2.11.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.11.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.11.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.11.0)
    rspec-core (2.11.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.11.3)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.3)
    rspec-mocks (2.11.3)
    rspec-rails (2.11.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec (~> 2.11.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.9)
    sass (3.2.9)
    sass-rails (3.2.5)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    selenium-webdriver (2.33.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.5)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rubyzip
      websocket (~> 1.0.4)
    slop (3.4.5)
    spork (0.9.2)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    therubyracer (0.11.4)
      libv8 (~> 3.11.8.12)
      ref
    thin (1.5.1)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.18.1)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.14)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.37)
    uglifier (1.2.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)
    underscore-rails (1.5.1)
    websocket (1.0.7)
    will_paginate (3.0.3)
    xpath (0.1.4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  annotate (= 2.5.0)
  bcrypt-ruby (= 3.0.1)
  bootstrap-sass
  bootstrap-will_paginate
  capybara (= 1.1.2)
  childprocess (= 0.3.9)
  coffee-rails (= 3.2.2)
  coffee-script
  cucumber-rails (= 1.2.1)
  database_cleaner (= 0.7.0)
  date_easter
  factory_girl_rails (= 4.1.0)
  faker (= 1.0.1)
  google_drive
  growl (= 1.0.3)
  guard-jasmine
  guard-rspec (= 1.2.1)
  guard-spork (= 1.5.0)
  highcharts-rails
  jasminerice!
  jquery-rails (= 2.0.2)
  jquery-ui-rails
  newrelic_rpm
  nokogiri
  omniauth-facebook
  pg (= 0.12.2)
  quiet_assets
  rails (= 3.2.11)
  rake (= 10.1.0)
  rb-fsevent (= 0.9.1)
  rspec-rails (= 2.11.0)
  sass-rails (= 3.2.5)
  spork (= 0.9.2)
  therubyracer
  thin
  uglifier (= 1.2.3)
  underscore-rails
  will_paginate (= 3.0.3)
```

gem list

```
actionmailer (4.0.0, 3.2.14, 3.2.11)
actionpack (4.0.0, 3.2.14, 3.2.11)
activemodel (4.0.0, 3.2.14, 3.2.11)
activerecord (4.0.0, 3.2.14, 3.2.11)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activeresource (4.0.0, 3.2.14, 3.2.11)
activesupport (4.0.0, 3.2.14, 3.2.11)
annotate (2.5.0)
arel (4.0.0, 3.0.2)
atomic (1.1.10)
bcrypt-ruby (3.1.1, 3.0.1)
bootstrap-sass (2.3.2.1)
bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.9)
builder (3.2.2, 3.1.4, 3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5, 1.3.0.pre.4, 1.1.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.1)
capybara (2.1.0, 1.1.2)
childprocess (0.3.9)
coderay (1.0.9)
coffee-rails (4.0.0, 3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
cucumber (1.3.5)
cucumber-rails (1.3.1, 1.2.1)
daemons (1.1.9)
database_cleaner (1.0.1, 0.7.0)
date_easter (0.0.1)
diff-lcs (1.2.4, 1.1.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.0.3)
execjs (1.4.0)
factory_girl (4.2.0, 4.1.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.2.1, 4.1.0)
faker (1.1.2, 1.0.1)
faraday (0.8.7)
ffi (1.9.0)
formatador (0.2.4)
gherkin (2.12.0)
google_drive (0.3.6)
growl (1.0.3)
guard (1.8.1, 1.7.0)
guard-jasmine (1.17.0)
guard-rspec (3.0.2, 1.2.1)
guard-spork (1.5.1, 1.5.0)
hashie (2.0.5)
highcharts-rails (3.0.2)
hike (1.2.3)
httpauth (0.2.0)
i18n (0.6.4)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (3.0.4, 2.0.2)
jquery-ui-rails (4.0.3)
json (1.8.0)
jwt (0.1.8)
libv8 (3.16.14.1, 3.11.8.17 x86_64-darwin-12)
listen (1.2.2, 0.7.3)
lumberjack (1.0.4)
mail (2.5.4, 2.4.4)
method_source (0.8.1)
mime-types (1.23)
mini_portile (0.5.1)
minitest (5.0.6, 4.7.5)
multi_json (1.7.7)
multi_test (0.0.2)
multi_xml (0.5.4)
multipart-post (1.2.0)
newrelic_rpm (3.6.5.130)
nokogiri (1.6.0)
oauth (0.4.7)
oauth2 (0.9.2, 0.8.1)
omniauth (1.1.4)
omniauth-facebook (1.4.1)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1)
pg (0.16.0, 0.12.2)
polyglot (0.3.3)
pry (0.9.12.2)
quiet_assets (1.0.2)
rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (4.0.0, 3.2.11)
rails-observers (0.1.2)
railties (4.0.0, 3.2.14, 3.2.11)
rake (10.1.0, 0.9.2.2)
rb-fsevent (0.9.3, 0.9.1)
rb-inotify (0.9.0)
rb-kqueue (0.2.0)
rdoc (4.0.1, 3.12.2)
ref (1.0.5)
rspec (2.14.1, 2.11.0)
rspec-core (2.14.4, 2.11.1)
rspec-expectations (2.14.0, 2.11.3)
rspec-mocks (2.14.1, 2.11.3)
rspec-rails (2.14.0, 2.11.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.2.2, 1.0.7)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
rvm (1.11.3.8, 1.11.3.5)
sass (3.2.9)
sass-rails (4.0.0, 3.2.5)
selenium-webdriver (2.33.0)
simplecov (0.7.1)
simplecov-html (0.7.1)
slop (3.4.5)
spork (0.9.2)
sprockets (2.10.0, 2.2.2)
sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
therubyracer (0.11.4)
thin (1.5.1)
thor (0.18.1)
thread_safe (0.1.2)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.14)
tzinfo (1.0.1, 0.3.37)
uglifier (2.1.2, 1.2.3)
underscore-rails (1.5.1)
websocket (1.1.1, 1.0.7)
will_paginate (3.0.4, 3.0.3)
xpath (2.0.0, 0.1.4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen dependency checking get confused at times with rvm. Cleaning up the gemset usually helps.

To diagnose, start with a clean gemset (create a new one) and run `bundle install`. If this happens again, I would suggest [submiting an issue](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues). If it doesn't then you can run with the new gemset.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Not sure why I missed it earlier. Since I'm still not very clear on rvm, would you mind telling what explicitly I would do create/use the new gemset within my existing project?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin To create a new gemset, see the instructions in http://rvm.io/gemsets/creating